# How to resize the OpenGL view larger than the size passed to the initial SDL_SetVideoMode?

Tags: opengl, sdl

I use OpenGL with the SDL and I want to keep the scene adjusted to the window when the latter is resized. For an unknown reason the scene is cropped at the initial window size when the window becomes larger.

The function used to adjust the view in response to a SDL_VIDEORESIZE is the following, where m_scene_{width,height} is the size of the view as seen by the game.

```
void screen::resize_view( width, height )
{
  // t will force the scene to be rendered with the top left corner matching the
  // one of the window.
  int t;

  if ( height < m_size.y )
    t = m_size.y - height;
  else
    t = 0;

  glViewport( 0, t, width, height );
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho( 0, m_scene_width, 0, m_scene_height, -1, 0 );
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

To initialize the window, I call

```
SDL_SetVideoMode( m_scene_width, m_scene_height 32,  SDL_OPENGL | SDL_RESIZABLE );
resize_view( m_scene_width, m_scene_height );
```

With this code, I have an initial window whose size matches the size of the view. Then if I reduce the size of the window on one or both dimension, the scene is effectively stretched to fit the window, with the top-left corner staying fixed.

But, if I enlarge the window on one or both dimensions, the scene becomes cropped on the right and the bottom as soon as the window become larger than the initial size passed to SDL_SetVideoMode(). Even if the content of the scene is effectively stretched to the expected size, these parts of the screen remain black.

Note that if I set glClearColor() to red, these parts are still black.

The only solution I have now is to call SDL_SetVideoMode() with the new size each time the window is resized, which is not acceptable since it invalidates the GL context on Windows and invalidates all the textures.

**Edit:** After some experiments I think that the black area is the result of the SDL_Surface initially created, that does not follow the size of the window. Thus, if I can resize this surface without destroying the GL context, I suppose it would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a newbie mistake, so common that I write it in about every 6th answer: The code you have in `resize_view` is code setting drawing state and hence belongs in the display/drawing function where you draw your scene as initial drawing setup. Use [`SDL_GetWindowSize`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_GetWindowSize?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryVideo%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29%7C%28SGFunctions%29) to retrieve the window size and set the viewport and projection just before drawing.

Keep in mind, that this is the *only* reasonable way to do it, because later on, you very likely may want to add some HUD, or a minimap or some UI controls and when those are added you must re-set the viewport and projection several times throughout rendering a single frame. So all the turorials setting the viewport and projection in some window resize handler effectively set up sort of a "mental roadblock", which gets people struggling with implementing such things. Your problems with the viewport not following the window size is similar.

Comment: SDL_GetWindowSize is not available in SDL 1.2.15. I tried to keep track of the size of the window and I moved the resize_view at the beginning of the drawing function but it does not solve anything. I think that the drawing is limited to the SDL_Surface created at initialization.